# Spring Cloud Contract - how to test simple string response?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm using Spring Cloud Contract framework for REST services integration testing and related client apps contracts. It works for object JSON request / response, but is there a chance to check simple string. Espetially, service which responses Boolean (true or false in response body)?

Part of groovy definition:

```
response {
    status 200
    headers {
        header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    }
    body(
        value(client('true'), server(regex("true|false")))
    )
}
```

Related part of generated test:

```
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    null;
```

Is it a bug, isn't it? Or should I do something better in groovy definition? First row gives a chance generator understands what I want, but second line is completely out. Thanks for any hint.

P.S. I know there are different opinions about only string "true" validity as JSON response (some people says so, other not) Please, don't solve it, but only the real issue :-)

Comment: That's not a bug, because this JSON is completely invalid. Try changing the content-type to sth else like `text/plain` and see if it works fine. If not then this indeed is a bug

Comment: "true" is valid JSON.

Comment: That's what I said in P.S. There are many opinions, but I din't find any valid reason that non-map/non-array value must be invalid JSON.

Comment: IMO, generated java code "null;" looks as a bug anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The issue got fixed here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/443 . With the new releases (Dalston.SR5 and Edgware forward) this no longer will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath ('url')

```
    body([
             'json-string'
        ])
    headers {
        header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    }
}
response {
    status 200
    body( "\"true\"" )
} }
```

This is worked for me.